# Background size is half of div

Tags: css, background-image

I need a background that has 50% width of div (from the left edge to center). And background image should not change proportions when the screen is changed. Now I have css:

```css
.bg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: url(../img.png);            
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 50vw 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 50vw 100%; /* browser support */
  -moz-background-size: 50vw 100%; /* browser support */
  -o-background-size: 50vw 100%; /* browser support */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="container-xl">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

dimensions of img: 1043*735

But image changes proportions (is compressed or stretched) on different screens. Is there a way to do image 'cover' but still half of div?

Comment: Can you provide the dimensions of your photo or an absolute reference?

Comment: It is 1043x735px

Answer (score 0):

Add a left padding covering half the width and clip your background to the content-box then you can use cover:

```css
.bg {
  height:100vh;
  padding-left:50%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300);
  background-position:center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-origin:content-box;
  background-clip:content-box;
}


body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: It does not work for me, I think padding-left does not related to background

Comment: @Newta does it work here in the snippet?